# Linear Support Vector Machines multiclass classification with PySpark API

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, svm, apache-spark-mllib

Support Vector Machines currently does not yet support multi class classification within Spark, but will in the future as it is described on the Spark [page](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-classification-regression.html).

Is there any release date or any chance to run it with PySpark API that implements multi class with Support Vector Machines? Thank you for any insights.

Answer (score 3):

In practice you can perform multiclass classification using an arbitrary binary classifier and one-vs-rest strategy. `mllib` doesn't provide one (there is one in `ml`) but you can easily built your own. Assuming data looks like this

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(323)

classes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def make_point(classes):
    label = np.random.choice(classes)
    features = np.random.random(len(classes))
    features[label] += 10
    return LabeledPoint(label, features)

data  = sc.parallelize([make_point(classes) for _ in range(1000)])

xs = data.take(5)
```

we can train separate model for each class:

```
def model_for_class(c, rdd):
    def adjust_label(lp):
        return LabeledPoint(1 if lp.label == c else 0, lp.features)

    model = SVMWithSGD.train(rdd.map(adjust_label))
    model.clearThreshold()
    return model

models = [model_for_class(c, data) for c in classes]
```

and use it for prediction:

```
[(x.label, np.argmax([model.predict(x.features) for model in models]))
for x in xs]
## [(0.0, 0), (1.0, 1), (0.0, 0), (5.0, 5), (2.0, 2)]
```

On the side note you cannot expect any further developments in `pyspark.mllib` because it is getting deprecated in favor of `ml`.